# How to block website with all subdomains in C#?

Tags: c#, dns, block

I'd like to make an application, who blocks website with all subdomains. driver/etc/hosts can't do this. Do you know, how library, dll or api should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: You would need to write a kernel module - and you cannot load CLR/C# code into a Windows driver... (not easily, at least).

Comment: It would be easier to put in a proxy server - which technically you CAN write in c# but why reinvent the wheel, then you can block it